# .substring() is not working

Tags: java, math

I'm working on a square root function in Java and I need it to take the number beginning on character 5, ending on the second last one. It currently displays "sqrt([NUMBER])". I've tried to use substring but it doesn't work. I've put my code below.

```
a = Math.sqrt( Double.parseDouble(t.getText().substring( 4, t.getText().length() - 1)));
```

Comment: Why do you want it to input a string?

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a useful error description. Please provide more details.

Comment: Sounds like you are incorrectly using substring(). Here is a hint, length() - 1 points to the last character in your string.

Comment: Because I'm using a textfield as an input source.

Comment: what is the error that you get?

Comment: I can't explain the error. I get about 50 rows of error messages in Eclipse.

Comment: It says "error due to empty String"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String s = "sqrt(1.234)";
 System.out.println(s.substring(5, s.length()-1));`

returns

`1.234`

Comment: @iheanyi I just ran this in my IDE, and isn't this what he wants?

Comment: you're right, for some reason I didn't count the "(" just the sqrt. According to the documentation, substring is inclusive of the start index but **exclusive** of the end index, so you are completely correct. This is what I get for assuming what the doc would say w/o reading it :)